# looking for a wikipedia api that can give me their article in XML

Tags: wikipedia-api

I am looking for a wikipedia api that can give me an article (no image) to a respective query.
I have seen the wikipedia api used with `actions=opensearch` and `query=search`.
Please tell me which one is correct or if there is any other `action` I should use.

Answer (score 4):

See the [WikiMedia API help](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) or the [complete documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API).

It's not clear what you are hoping to have returned to you, an article or search results.  Either way, to get results in xml, use `format=xml`.

To get a listing of articles that match a certain query, use the [`opensearch` action](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aOpensearch).  For example:
`http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=MediaWiki&format=xml` - [View the results](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=MediaWiki&format=xmlfm)

From the section on `action=opensearch` in the [API help](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php):

```
* action=opensearch *
  Searches the wiki using the OpenSearch protocol

This module requires read rights
Parameters:
  search     - Search string
  limit      - Maximum amount of results to return
               No more than 100 (100 for bots) allowed
               Default: 10
  namespace  - Namespaces to search
               Values (separate with '|'): 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
                   13, 14, 15
               Maximum number of values 50 (500 for bots)
               Default: 0
  suggest    - Do nothing if $wgEnableOpenSearchSuggest is false
  format     - Output format defaults to JSON, with expanded XML optional.
               One value: json, jsonfm, xml, xmlfm
               Default: json
Example:
  api.php?action=opensearch&search=Te
```

To get the contents of a specific article, use the [`parse` action](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext#parse).  For example:
`http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=MediaWiki&format=xml` - [View the results](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=MediaWiki&format=xmlfm)

From the section on `action=parse` in the [API help](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php):

```
* action=parse *
  Parses wikitext and returns parser output

This module requires read rights
Parameters:
  title       - Title of page the text belongs to
                Default: API
  text        - Wikitext to parse
  summary     - Summary to parse
  page        - Parse the content of this page. Cannot be used together with
                    text and title
  pageid      - Parse the content of this page. Overrides page
  redirects   - If the page or the pageid parameter is set to a redirect, resolve it
  oldid       - Parse the content of this revision. Overrides page and pageid
  prop        - Which pieces of information to get
                 text           - Gives the parsed text of the wikitext
                 langlinks      - Gives the language links in the parsed wikitext
                 categories     - Gives the categories in the parsed wikitext
                 categorieshtml - Gives the HTML version of the categories
                 languageshtml  - Gives the HTML version of the language links
                 links          - Gives the internal links in the parsed wikitext
                 templates      - Gives the templates in the parsed wikitext
                 images         - Gives the images in the parsed wikitext
                 externallinks  - Gives the external links in the parsed wikitext
                 sections       - Gives the sections in the parsed wikitext
                 revid          - Adds the revision ID of the parsed page
                 displaytitle   - Adds the title of the parsed wikitext
                 headitems      - Gives items to put in the  of the page
                 headhtml       - Gives parsed  of the page
                 iwlinks        - Gives interwiki links in the parsed wikitext
                 wikitext       - Gives the original wikitext that was parsed
                Values (separate with '|'): text, langlinks, languageshtml,
                    categories, categorieshtml, links, templates, images,
                    externallinks, sections, revid, displaytitle, headitems,
                    headhtml, iwlinks, wikitext
                Default: text|langlinks|categories|links|templates|images|
                         externallinks|sections|revid|displaytitle
  pst         - Do a pre-save transform on the input before parsing it
                Ignored if page, pageid or oldid is used
  onlypst     - Do a pre-save transform (PST) on the input, but don't parse it
                Returns the same wikitext, after a PST has been applied. Ignored if
                    page, pageid or oldid is used
  uselang     - Which language to parse the request in
  section     - Only retrieve the content of this section number
  disablepp   - Disable the PP Report from the parser output
Example:
  api.php?action=parse&text={{Project:Sandbox}}
```

Comment: The OP might also want `action=query` with [`prop=revisions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties#revisions_.2F_rv), if they're interested in the raw wikitext instead of parsed HTML output.  (I'm not 100% sure if that's more efficient than `action=parse` with `prop=wikitext`, but I suspect it is.)

Comment: u mean to say i have to use action=parse to get the result as an article.If yes can you tell me if i have to get an article on india .what all i have to do.plzzzz

Comment: @shivamoberoi - I'm not sure how much more information I can give you.  If you want, I'll just write your code for you... my rate is $100/hr.

Comment: I got the article in XML format by using action=parse but i want to edit an article by removing all the image link and infobox ,only text to be printed.iam using java language for this.

Comment: few prop argument values like wikitext, text are not working here. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&pageids=26291&format=json&prop=wikitext 
but others like images etc working fine. what am i missing ? in can't find these arguments in wikipedia documentation also.

Comment: @Dashrath - You are using `action=query`.  To get wikitext you need `action=parse`: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&pageid=26291&format=jsonfm&prop=wikitext  (I used `format=jsonfm` here so that clicking the link yields a readable result.  For your code, use `format=json`.)

Comment: @gilly3 What does `suggest` in `opensearch` do? Can't seem to figure out...